# What MySQL Tables Should I Have for a Comprehensive Worldbuilding & Storytelling Platform?

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry if this doesn't belong here. I'm not sure if general advise questions are allowed here or if this should be somewhere like Reddit. Just let me know if that's the case.

As a fun side project, I'm in the early stages of planning/building my own comprehensive worldbuilding and storytelling platform—meant for worldbuilding, character creation, D&D campaign creation/management, writing, etc. However, I'm entirely new to the world of MySQL and database management. Where I'm in need of guidance is in regard to common database table practices for websites this involved. More specifically, what areas I should create a table for. In my planning stages, I've come up with...

1. Users
2. Activity_Log
3. Character_General
4. Character_Appearance
5. Character_Traits
6. Character_Inventory
7. Character_Relationships
8. DnD_Campaign
9. Magic_Types
10. World_General
11. World_Geography
12. World_History
13. World_Cosmology
14. World_Ecology
    ...

The list goes on, but you get the idea. The goal is to build a robust platform with massive interconnectivity through its various features and offerings. What I'm really trying to wrap my head around is just how in-depth I should go with the tables I create, and the pros and cons to creating a bunch of tables and "sub-tables."

On the other hand, I don't want to overcomplicate things due to a lack of understanding what really is and is not important when it comes to database tables.

Answer (score 1):

- No subtables
- Think about the "Entities": Users, Log entries, Characters, Campaigns, etc.  Each should be 1 table with lots of rows.  Example: 1 row per user.
- Then think about "Relationships" -- 1 user to many characters, many users to many campaigns.  (or whatever)
- A table has a `PRIMARY KEY` (usually named `id`) that uniquely identifies each row.  Example:  user-login-id, arbitrary campaign number.
- A table has attributes of the item (user's real name, some date, character's strength, etc.)

There are 3 ways to implement Relationships between tables:

- 1-1 -- They share the same "primary key" (often named `id`).  But, usually, the 2 tables should be folded into a single table.
- 1-many -- The "many" table has the "id" of the one row in the "one" table.
- many-to-many -- An extra table with 2 columns.  Each row is a pair of ids, 1 for each of the 2 tables.  The Primary Key for such a table would be the pair if id columns.

(I have never played DnD, so I cannot get more specific.)

Each "Character" has several 'general' and 'appearance' attributes, correct?  Those sound like columns in the `Character` table.

The `Traits` sounds like many traits for each character?  Potentially 0 or 1 or many -- a many-to-1 relationship in any case.

Ditto for table `Inventory`.

`Relationships` sounds like many-to-many with pairs of `character_ids`.  Is a "relationship" 'symmetric'.

In other words, let the x-to-y drive the schema.

Don't clutter table names with the prefix `Character_` -- It makes for more typing and the queries are harder to read.  You will instinctively know that a "trait" applies to a "character", not a "world".

Usually, columns should be declared `NOT NULL`.  Or, instead, `NULL` can be used to represent "not applicable", "optional", "not yet set", etc.

Comment: so rather than Character_[Sub-item], I should only have a Character table and everything else should be row items of that table? Same with World and any other tables? I guess the main area I thought that would become a problem is when it comes to character inventories and such. I assumed for easier management purposes I would need that to be its own table. Is that incorrect/overthinking? I very easily could be overthinking the whole thing since this is my first MySQL project.

Comment: I added some...